# Syntax error: "fi" unexpected

Tags: bash, shell, syntax-error

I am trying to write a shell script that will either start or stop openvpn, depending on what the user enters. When I run the script it correctly prompts me for what I want to do. But when I type "1" and hit [Enter] it outputs this and terminates:

```
./control-openvpn.sh: 27: ./control-openvpn.sh: Syntax error: "fi" unexpected
```

Here is the main part of my code. The functions are above it in the script.

```
# Main
echo -n "What to do? 1.Start or 2.Stop. [1/2]"
read action
if [ "$action" == "1" ]
then
    start_openvpn()
elif [ "$action" == "2" ]
then
    stop_openvpn()
fi
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Shell functions are not called with `()`. Those are confusing the parser. Remove them.

Comment: ./control-openvpn.sh: 21: [: 1: unexpected operator
    ./control-openvpn.sh: 24: [: 1: unexpected operator
This is what I get now

Comment: Take a look at http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: That code without `()` on those two lines is completely valid. If you get other errors after removing those then you have problems with some other line or you changed something else as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash, when you do start_openvpn(), you are declaring a new function. Thus, bash gets confused when the next thing it sees is fi. Something like this should work for you:

```
read -p 'What to do? 1.Start or 2.Stop. [1/2] ' action
if [ $action -eq 1 ]; then
    start_openvpn
elif [ $action -eq 2 ]; then
    stop_openvpn
fi
```

Comment: thanks that works perfectly (i think) how can I test to see that openvpn is actually running

Comment: You could just telnet to the server via the openvpn port. If it is listening it'll reply. If it isn't then it won't.